# “Unexpected error” when trying to get back Chrome OS from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, chromebook, chromeos

How do I get back Chrome OS from Ubuntu 13.04? It keeps saying "unexpected error" when I use Chrome recovery. I have already tried two flash drives, but they didn't work because their capacity was less than 4 gigabytes. I was using Ubuntu 13.04 when I restarted my computer because of lag.

When I booted up Ubuntu, it already said there was errors, ignored them. I got Google Chrome web browser for it, and it was super lag at the time. So what was going though my head was to restart it, I did and all it said was "Chrome OS is damaged or missing" So I tried the USB recovery, but it always says

> Unexpected error, please try again. Go to the Google Forums to seek help.

```
HWID: PARROT CUTLASSFISH A-E 3149
recovery_reason: 0x50  TPM setup error in read-only firmware
VbSD.flags: 0x00000640
VbNv.raw: 70 20 00 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f8
dev_boot_usb: 0
dev_boot_signed_only: 0
TPM: fwver=0x00000000 kernver=0x00000000
gbb.flags: 0x00000000
gbb.rootkey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
gbb.recovery_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
read-only firmware id : Google.Parrot.2685.54.0
active firmware id : Google.Parrot.2685.54.0
```

Comment: Btw when i was in ubuntu 13.04 i restarted and it did this ^

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You haven't mentioned what your setup was, how you installed Ubuntu and what the exact error is.

Comment: Sorry Shah but i got it for christmas and now im panicking, anyway, its a Acer C710 Chromebook, so i installed Ubuntu 13.04 by using the ctrl+alt+f2 and then i just typed in this code i got, once it finished it was running alitle slow but it was usable since chromebooks are a browser with a keyboard. after that i installed chrome with 'google-chrome-stable' then it froze, but i could still move the mouse, so i restarted it and i did not put the code where it automatically boots for you, instead i got a Chrome Os is missing or damaged, AND the recovery also doesnt work :(

Comment: What was the code you typed in the ctrl+alt+f2 screen? Can you locate the instructions that you followed?

Comment: Yes i can handuel, here is what i followed :/

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=sjjTdw2mB4k

Comment: [Edit] your question and include what you did

Comment: Please, clean your now obsolete comments, also, exactly what was done before that provoked the problem?

Comment: Let me put this in the most clear and crystal cleanest way possible, Eh?    Ubuntu stopped and it restarted. Causing to delete Chrome Operating System, so i couldn't go into Ubuntu Anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format a USB on Ubuntu if you do not have a formatted one  any format is OK, capacity 4GB+).

1) Boot into Ubuntu and open Terminal.
Type: `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 1 /dev/sda`
Then type `reboot`
This will boot you back into Chrome OS

2) ctrl+d to skip OS veritifcation, login to your google account.

3) Insert a Blank USB

4) Open the chrome browser and go to *chrome://imageburner*

5) Burn the image

6) Remove the USB once finished

7) Turn off the device then hold *ESC+REFRESH+POWER*

8) Recover your device.

Comment: Sorry, but its not Ubuntu to Chrome, its reversed, but im stuck at the "Chrome OS is missing or damaged" Thanks for the help btw

Comment: If it says missing or damaged press CTRL+D and it should skip that message.

Comment: I did, but its not doing anything, but just sitting there. When I press Tab it pops up this black text to tell me what happened, do you want to take a look at it?

Comment: I'd like to take a look

Comment: HWID: PARROT CUTLASSFISH A-E 3149  

recovery_reason: 0x50 TPM setup error in read-only firmware 

VbSD.flags: 0x00000640  

VbNv.raw: 70 20 00 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f8   

dev_boot_usb: 0  

dev_boot_signed_only: 0  

TPM: fwver=0x00000000 kernver=0x00000000  
 
gbb.flags: 0x00000000   

gbb.rootkey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  

gbb.recovery_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  

read-only firmware id : Google.Parrot.2685.54.0  

active firmware id : Google.Parrot.2685.54.0

Comment: I followed the same tutorial as you but I didn't get any errors,
Haven't you tried powering off and pressing ESC+REFRESH(f3)+POWER to prompt recovery wizard?

Comment: Yes I have, and every time I try to get it to upload my recovery USB it always says "Unexpected error has occured" and redirects me to Google. :/  (Srry Moderators that i am having a disscussion, but im too low of a level to start a chat, please excuse this one, thanks)

Comment: By redirects you to google, you mean it boots into Chrome OS?

Comment: Nope, Every time I press the power button when its off it goes to the "Chrome OS is missing or damaged" screen, cant do nothing. (EDIT) once i did the ESC+REFRESH+POWER, it went into "To turn OS verification OFF, Press ENTER. Your system will reboot and local data will be cleared. To go back, press ESC."

Comment: If you feel comfortable opening your Chromebook check this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SguP3C7C5c4

It isn't anything serious, just unplugging a wire out and back in.

Comment: Try turning OS verification back on (so it wipes the SSD but keeps ChromeOS) and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Alright man, it will void my warranty but are you 100% guaranteed? or atleast like 80 to 100%

Comment: It won't void your warranty (it explained in the video) it might work as some people have had to come across this too.

Comment: Alright im going to try it, until then, Stand By...

Comment: Okay, good luck